# connect a mac or windows pc to a eon612 speacker

Tags: speakers, pc

I have a eon612 speaker and I would like to have it play tracks from my PC windows pc 3.5mm jack.

Do I need an amplifier between the pc and eon612? Is there a low cost solutions? can it be done with a simple ts to xlr cable.

Answer (score 0):

In1 and In2 on the eon612 are dual XLR/jack sockets.  So use the jack option.  Switch the Mic/Line selector to Line.

You need a cable with a stereo 3.5mm jack on one end, two mono 1/4" jack plugs on the other.    You might find this easier to arange with a stereo 3.5mm jack to two phono plugs cable, plus a couple of phono to jack adapters.   Your eon612 is a powered system, so no further amplificxation is needed.